# How to remove and re-enable share permission

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008-r2

How do I remove and re-enable share permissions in powershell with my existing shared folder?

Example:

**Shared Permission Details:**

- Shared location: `\\Server\Temp`
- Server folder path: `C:\Temp`
- User: `Authenticated Users`
- Permission: `Read (Read Only)`

I don't need to modify the NTFS permissions. It should be there already because this is an existing shared folder.

**NTFS Permission Details:**
Authenticated Users

Comment: Check this out https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Create-a-Share-and-Set-eb177a79.

Comment: What do you mean by "remove and re-enable share permissions"? If you need to change share permissions: just apply the new ACL. If something doesn't work: please describe the problem rather than what you perceive as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to do something similar to the following,

```
Revoke-SmbShareAccess -name ShareName -CimSession ServerName -AccountName Everyone -Force
Grant-SmbShareAccess -name ShareName -CimSession ServerName -AccountName Everyone -AccessRight Read –Force
```

Update: for 2008 you will need to use WMI, take a look at the following, [WMI](http://windowsitpro.com/powershell/managing-file-shares-windows-powershell)

Comment: The SMB cmdlets are not available prior to Server 2012. He has Server 2008 R2.

Comment: I don't have the Get-SMBShare commandlet. How do i enable it? I think it's disabled on Powershell v4.0 (installer). I installed PowerShell 4.0 on my 2008 R2 server and I know the commandlet is available in Windows Server 2012, where it uses PowerShell 4.0.

Comment: I should be able to import the smb module by using Import-Module SmbShare. But it seems like PowerShell 4.0 is not correctly installed on my Win 2008 R2 server. Do you guys know any known issues regarding powershell upgrade installation? Also, is other commands I could use that's PowerShell 2.0 compatible?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers where does it say that he has 2008?

Comment: @user3911596 you should just have to install .net Framework version 4.0 (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40855)

Comment: @Luke First in the subject, then I moved it to the tags where it belongs. And no, installing .NET Framework 4.0 does not add the SMB cmdlets. Like I said: they're not available prior to Windows Server 2012.

Comment: I did that. I just checked that the reason why SmbShare was added during the installation is that it's not compatible with win 2008.

Comment: @user3911596 okay so I found the answer for 2008, I edited my answer to include it

Answer (score -1):

You can can modify permissions to shares using the following cmdlets

```
Get-SMBShare "Sharename" | Revoke-SMBShareAccess -AccountName "Username"
Get-SMBShare "ShareName" | Grant-SMBShareAccess -Account "Username" -AccessRight "Full/Change/Read"
```

Comment: The SMB cmdlets are not available prior to Server 2012. He has Server 2008 R2.

Comment: I don't have the Get-SMBShare commandlet. How do i enable it? I think it's disabled on Powershell v4.0 (installer). I installed PowerShell 4.0 on my 2008 R2 server and I know the commandlet is available in Windows Server 2012, where it uses PowerShell 4.0.

Comment: I should be able to import the smb module by using Import-Module SmbShare. But it seems like PowerShell 4.0 is not correctly installed on my Win 2008 R2 server. Do you guys know any known issues regarding powershell upgrade installation? Also, is other commands I could use that's PowerShell 2.0 compatible?